# Is there an easy way to see which answer is the oldest?

Tags: support, answers

When browsing questions, it occurs at times that I notice that among the answers there are some that are mostly identical, or highly derivative without attribution.

In the case where these answers were provided recently (less than an hour ago), I can determine which answer was given the earliest, as it will display the elapsed time in minutes. Also, when the answers were provided a while ago, I can determine this from the time stamp that is shown for the answer. In between these two time spans, it shows the elapsed time in an hours resolution making it impossible (or difficult?) to tell which one is the oldest.

The situation where I would care about this is when I would like to upvote a good answer, but would rather not reward a potential "copy cat".

So my question is: is there some, preferably easy, way to find out when an answer was posted, or any other means to determine which answer is the oldest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the answers by "oldest":

[image: sort by oldest]

However, the accepted answer will still be on top.  You can get the exact time (including seconds) it was posted by hovering your cursor over the date.

Comment: Well, that is embarrassing. How could I overlook something so obvious.